# Stopping lisp from asking user for input

Tags: emacs, lisp, prompt

I am trying to modify the igrep.el package to perform specific functionality.
When performing M-x igrep-find the package asks user for type of files with "current buffer" type as default.
I want to default file types to grep on to be *.[sch] so I added the line:

(defvar default-files-string-new "*.[sch]")

I am trying to modify the following function to stop asking user for type of files and just default silently to the variable specified above.

```
(defvar default-files-string-new "*.[sch]")
(defun igrep-read-files (&optional prompt-prefix)
  "Read and return a file name pattern from the minibuffer.
If `current-prefix-arg' is '(16) or '(64), read multiple file name
patterns and return them in a list.  Optional PROMPT-PREFIX is
prepended to the \"File(s): \" prompt."
  (let* ((default-files (igrep-default-files))
         (default-files-string (mapconcat 'identity default-files " "))
         (insert-default-directory igrep-insert-default-directory)
         (file (igrep-read-file-name
                (igrep-prefix prompt-prefix
                              (if default-files
                                  (format "File(s) [default: %s]: "
                                          default-files-string)
                                "File(s): "))
                nil (if default-files default-files-string "") nil nil
                'igrep-files-history))
         (files (list file)))
    (if (or igrep-read-multiple-files
            (and (consp current-prefix-arg)
                 (memq (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
                       '(16 64))))
        (let* ((key (igrep-default-key 'exit-minibuffer
                                       minibuffer-local-completion-map
                                       "\r"))
               (prompt
                (igrep-prefix prompt-prefix
                              (if igrep-verbose-prompts
                                  (format "File(s): [Type `%s' when done] "
                                          (key-description key))
                                "File(s): "))))
          (while (and (setq file
                            (igrep-read-file-name prompt
                                                  nil "" nil nil
                                                  'igrep-files-history))
                      (not (equal file "")))
            (setq files (cons file files)))))
    (mapcar (lambda (file)
              (if (file-directory-p file)
                  ;; really should map expand-file-name over default-files:
                  (expand-file-name (if default-files default-files-string-new "*")
                                    file)
                file))
            (nreverse files))))
```

Comment: I know Lisp is hard to read, but please format this better.

Comment: Thanks mohammad. i did already.

Comment: My guess would be that whatever `igrep-read-file-name` does, it does it interactively, so you should look at what it does and replace it with something that doesn't require interaction.

Comment: wvxvw Thank you for looking into this.
I actually have been looking into this igrep-read-file-name replacing/modifying inside it...nothing worked for me.
I simply want the code to not ask the user for input and accept the default value *.[sch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand. If you don't want input wouldn't it be easier to just completely replace the function?

```
(defvar default-files-string-new "*.sch")
(defun igrep-read-files (&optional prompt-prefix)
  `(,(expand-file-name (concat default-directory
                               default-files-string-new))))
```

Comment: ahilsend yes :)
Exactly! That worked perfectly.
I wish I have enough reps to upvote your answer

Comment: Ahilsend...
Maybe you can help me with my other confusion.
For the same piece of code, how would I modify it so that I would allow the user to enter his input "once".
Meaning, there is another option for igrep.el to ask for path to grep in. I want the user to either accept the default path or enter a new one and then all new grep searches would default to the specified path. without keep asking the user for the path.